# SFINAE on default parameter value

Tags: c++, templates, constructor, arguments, default

Consider the following code.

```
template <typename Metadata>
struct S {
        double data;
        Metadata metadata;
        explicit S(double d = 0., Metadata const & m = Metadata()) :
                data(d), metadata(m)
        {}
};

struct NoDefaultConstructor {
        NoDefaultConstructor(int) {}
};

struct PrivateDefaultConstructor {
        PrivateDefaultConstructor(int) {}
private:
        PrivateDefaultConstructor() {}
};
```

The following compiles without problem:

```
S<float> sf;
```

As expected, the following code samples fail to compile:

```
S<NoDefaultConstructor> sndc;
S<NoDefaultConstructor> sndc(1);
S<PrivateDefaultConstructor> spdc;
S<PrivateDefaultConstructor> spdc(1);
```

But what about the following:

```
S<NoDefaultConstructor> sndc(1, 1);
S<PrivateDefaultConstructor> spdc(1, 1);
```

It compiles fine with GCC 4.4.1, but what has the standard to say about it? Should I expect an error at template instantiation of `S` with `NoDefaultConstructor` or `PrivateDefaultConstructor`?

More generally, does SFINAE apply on default parameters values?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should compile fine because there are no need to invoke default constructor when the second parameter is explicitly specified (only conversion constructor from int and copy constructor are invoked).

Note: it is not related to SFINAE

Comment: copy constructor and the conversion constructor from `int`.

Comment: Thanks. And what if `S`'s constructor used not `Metadata()` as default value for parameter `m` but a construct like `typename Metadata::type()`? Should it compile when instanciated with, say `float`, if a value is passed for this parameter?

Comment: @Christophe Fuzier: For instance, ...Metadata const & m = Metadata(3.1415926)) should work (if public conversion ctor from int or float is provided by class Metadata). The expression specified as default value is called on behalf of the caller, so the caller should have rights to evaluate this expression. It is not specific for constructors, any member access should respect access specifiers like privat, protected, etc....

Comment: OK, this is what I thought but I needed a confirmation. I think the important part of your comment is "the expression as default value is called **on behalf of the caller**", which means that using default values for parameters for a constructor or any other function works exactly like writing several overloads. Thanks. Solved.

Comment: Ok, but I should corect myself: default initalizer expression is _invoked_ on behalf of the caller, but may involve something visible only from within class S, for instance, private static member functions defined in class S _can_ be invoked. Of course, private members of Metadata can't be invoked anyway